# How to store increment values in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Here's my question: For one of my assignments, I was tasked with developing a lisp program that takes 2 lists as input, one symbolizing a shopping cart (L1) with an item name and quantity, the second one symbolizing a price list (L2), with the item name and price. Everything follows this format:

```
(calcTotal '(shirtA 3 shirtB 1) '(shirtA 25 shirtB 55))

The total is 155.00
```

Here's my code below:

```
(defun calcTotal (L1 L2 &aux(Ttl 0))
(cond
    (
        (and (listp L1) (listp L2))

        (do
            ((tLst1 L1 (cddr tLst1)))

            ((equal tLst1 nil) Ttl)

            (do
                ((tLst2 L2 (cddr tLst2)))

                ((equal tLst2 nil) nil)

                (cond
                    (
                        (equal (car tLst1) (car tLst2))

                        (print (+ Ttl (* (cadr tLst1) (cadr tLst2))))
                    )
                )

            )

        )

    )
)
)
```

Basically, what it does is check for the name of the item in the first list, then search for it in the second list. Once it finds a match, multiply their values together to get the total for that item, then remove the first two elements in the first list, and repeat. The problem is that the total (Ttl) does not accumulate. I can get the amount for each item specifically, but for some reason Ttl returns as 0. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: I propose you indent and format the code using the typical Lisp conventions. Parentheses on their own lines does not help much. Correct indenting (which is supported by editors) and parentheses matching helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just print out the value. To keep it for later, also *set* the variable:

```
;; (print (+ Ttl (* (cadr tLst1) (cadr tLst2)))) 
   (setf Ttl (+ Ttl (* (cadr tLst1) (cadr tLst2))))
   (print Ttl)
```

Comment: ... In the words of Homer Simpson, "D'oh!" Thank you.

Comment: @S.T.A.L.K.E.R. you're welcome. study the other answers here, they give you valuable information on how to proceed beyond the initial most simple coding style of iteration and side effects (that is, changing a variable's value).

Answer (score 9):

There are at least three approaches:

1. use primitive Lisp to practice recursion in a functional programming language
2. use higher order functions: MAP and REDUCE, and a side-effect-free programming style
3. use iteration and side effects

I'll show you approach 2:

One important tool is *functional abstraction*. Use functions to implement self-contained functionality, which can be reused and which can be easily tested.

You need a price. Write a `GET-PRICE` function.

```
(defun get-price (item price-list)
  (getf price-list item))
```

Above makes use of the price-list being a *property list*. `GETF` does the look-up. You can re-implement it as a task.

Applying a function over a list and collecting the return values is called *mapping' in list. Unfortunately Lisp provides mapping functions which take one item a time, not two. We write one:

```
(defun map2 (function list)
  (loop for (a b) on list by #'cddr
        collect (funcall function a b)))
```

`MAP2` maps over a list and applies a function on the first and second argument, then the third and fourth, ... it collects the results in a new list, which is returned then.

Above makes use of the `LOOP` construct. You can re-implement it using `DO` as a task.

```
(defun calc-total (cart price-list)
  (reduce #'+
          (map2 (lambda (item n)
                  (* n (get-price item price-list)))
                cart)))
```

Above uses two higher-order functions: `REDUCE` and `MAP2`. Higher-order means that they take functions as parameters. `REDUCE` is a library function in Common Lisp. We use it to sum up a list of numbers. With `MAP2` we compute the price for each shopping cart element by multiplying the number of items with the price per item.

```
CL-USER > (calc-total '(shirtA 3 shirtB 1) '(shirtA 25 shirtB 55))
130
```

**SUMMARY**

Above approach has several advantages:

1. we have small/compact functions which are easy to understand and test
2. no visible side effects
3. the basic model of mapping and reducing is a pattern that appears often in list processing and is easy to understand
4. the functions are easy to combine
5. the 'MAP2' function is a new useful reusable tool
6. the code layout is much better to read

For the other approaches here are hints:

1. you need to use a recursive call
2. you need to use a variable for the sum, add the prices as a side effect and return the sum at the end.

Answer (score 8):

Your data structures are Lisp property lists: flat lists of alternating key and value pairs (called property "indicators" and property values).

Therefore, you should take advantage of Lisp's property list manipulating functions like `getf` which looks up a key and retrieves the value.

Also, the `loop` macro is of great help here. It excels at summation jobs like this.

```
(defun calculate-total (cart prices)
  (loop for (item units) on cart by #'cddr
        for unit-price = (getf prices item)
        if unit-price
          sum (* unit-price units)
        else
          do (error "price check on ~s please!" item)))
```

Notice how we nicely close parentheses like this `)))`.  When Lisp code is properly formatted, you train your brain not to see the parentheses. Don't waste your time lining up what you will train yourself not to see anyway.